# How to divide a ER digram into multiple microservices

Tags: microservices, erd, monolithic

I have a ER diagram and I want to divide it so I can implement multiple microservices

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7sVj.png)

I used to implement monolithic type, is there a guideline on how to divide ER diagram into microservices?

For example, user microservice would have (user table, user type table). I have these table car part, car, country, complaint, shop?

Answer (score 2):

In the microservices architecture, the established way of defining microservices is known as [decomposition by subdomain](https://microservices.io/patterns/decomposition/decompose-by-subdomain.html), which is a top-down approach, based on the [bounded contexts](https://medium.com/nick-tune-tech-strategy-blog/domains-subdomain-problem-solution-space-in-ddd-clearly-defined-e0b49c7b586c) of your system.

Once they're identified, you can then figure out the data access model that is appropriate (which tables should be used by each microservice).

So I would advise to follow that model, instead of going bottom-up, from the DB to the way microservices should be defined.

Comment: There are, in my experience, few surer ways to a failed microservice migration than to take a relational DB schema (especially one that's been normalized) and allocate tables to microservices.

Comment: Then what would suggest?

Comment: @LeviRamsey Completely agree that top-down approach might not be the best (or the fastest) option all the time. If it makes more sense to make it bottom-up, then I don't see any problem with that.

Comment: If I want to start bottom-up, how should I go about it?